# A resource to answer all those .htaccess and rewrite questions

Tags: discussion

Just ran across this Github repo:

https://github.com/phanan/htaccess

Nice collection of common things people ask about.

Just thought of sharing, could be useful to answer/close a lot of the rewrite questions which seems like no one want to answer anymore.

Comment: [Redirect, Change URLs or Redirect HTTP to HTTPS in Apache - Everything You Ever Wanted to Know About Mod_Rewrite Rules but Were Afraid to Ask](http://serverfault.com/questions/214512/redirect-change-urls-or-redirect-http-to-https-in-apache-everything-you-ever)???

Answer (score 12):

We already have a [nice resource for that particular problem](https://serverfault.com/questions/214512/redirect-change-urls-or-redirect-http-to-https-in-apache-everything-you-ever). The real issues are that

- No one who needs to, reads anything least of all documentation.
- No one who needs to, uses search.
- People would rather answer the question than close it as a duplicate
- Duplicates you know exist are [stupidly difficult to find](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/232242/help-us-find-duplicates-efficiently).

---

Personally I think that we should stop spoon feeding people people and start acting like the senior admins that these people are clearly lacking. Instead of giving people 'the code' answers we should provide pointers or ideas and make people work it out for themselves with nudges in the right direction. This would at least have the benefit of making the internet better s it will weed out the truly clueless and the cargocultists.

Comment: I agree with you on that. But giving the people pointers does not work well on SF because it becomes a deluge of comments. A lot of people answer when pointed to this *nice resource for that particular problem* is along the lines of "I saw that but MY problem is special and is not covered". It is of course covered but they don't have the pre-requisite to understand it or they are curses with one of today's man disease of the "quick fit pill".

Comment: @ETL They are the people who most need to learn how to do it for themselves. Give an answer that you know is correct and leads to a resolution with some effort on the OPS part, ignore the whingeing. Leave an answer - move on (possibly) harsh but the right thing to do to make in internet better.

Comment: I've always felt that sites like this should be in the business of fishing rods rather than fishes, so to speak.

Answer (score 10):

Most people who use .htaccess and ask about it on ServerFault should not be using .htaccess in the first place as that is an end-user solution never intended for administrators:

> You should **avoid using .htaccess files completely** if you have access to httpd main server config file. Using `.htaccess` files slows down your Apache http server. Any directive that you can include in a .htaccess file is better set in a Directory block, as it will have the same effect with better performance.
>   **Source:** [Apache manual](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/howto/htaccess.html)

But since most people who publish their configurations appear to be [cargo cult programmers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming) keen on copying .htaccess files blindly without understanding the reasons.